# Prevent backup of keychain data using kSecAttrAccessibleAfterFirstUnlockThisDeviceOnly

Tags: ios, file, synchronization, backup, keychain

I want to prevent a user from buying credits, synching their device, using the credits and then restoring their device from backup thereby resetting their credit level to what it was when they synched their device.  I read that keychain items with  `kSecAttrAccessibleAfterFirstUnlockThisDeviceOnly` "... do not migrate to a new device or new installation."  But this is never repeated and is not written for the very similar `kSecAttrAccessibleThisDeviceOnly`.  Can anyone confirm that such keychain items would not be backed up?

(I don't want to use a file in a cache directory because the user will lose their credits if they delete and reinstall the App.)

Comment: On reflection - perhaps another approach is to use two files and set NSURLIsExcludedFromBackup for one (A) and not the other (B).  Then if (A) and (B) are missing, assume a delete/reinstall and accept the backed up keychain.  If only (A) is missing assume a backup and reject the keychain.  Comments?